# Cannot configure Async Exception Handler with Spring task XML configured

Tags: spring

According to the Spring docs, one should be able to specify in the task:annotation-driven XML element a custom implementation of the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler interface.

If I try this:

```
   <task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" exception-handler="myExceptionHandler"/>
```

I get an error in Eclipse:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'exception-handler' is not allowed to appear in element 'task:annotation-driven
```

I'm using Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does the header of your spring configuration look like? Does it point to the version less or at least 4.2 xsd or not?

Comment: it was set to 4.0, that was the problem. With 4.2 it works